# Roslyn analyzer/codefix dependencies

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to write an analyzer with codefix and I'm unsure on how I can

1. Add a required base class to the consumer project. 
   *Preferred method would be to have it available at build time only (so generated)*
2. Add the required dependency that this base class has to the consumer project 
   so that compilation of the code fix does not fail. 
     *Maybe it's possible to check during analyze phase if that project has that dependency already installed?*

The base class is needed by the generated code from the code fix and inherently the dependency of a 3rd party nuget.

Comment: Could you add the roslyn code you have created to this point?

Comment: I'm moving from a generated code solution to a code fix solution and have not implemented the logic. I'm currently in a design phase thinking about requirements.